# azure: server-side SVG to PNG in node.js azure function app? nothing works

Tags: node.js, azure, svg, phantomjs, png

does anyone know how to convert SVG images to PNG (or JPG) on the server side? i've a node.js script that needs to do this and send the PNG to the caller. no rendering can be done on the client, it can only read PNGs or JPGs. i've looked at phantomjs, anychart-nodejs, canvas and others. they simply don't install or in the case of phantomjs, it installs and works in some cases and not in others. phantomjs works perfectly in node.js on a windows 10 computer, btw.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out. using the sharp js library did the trick. it's a bit difficult to get going, though. send me a message if you have trouble; i'll post my solution here.

Comment: Yes, please post your solution here.

Answer (score -1):

My idea is to render a SVG image to `canvas` HTML element and then to convert the `canvas` one to a `png` image.

Here is my sample code `demo.html` as below, which I am using a pure JavaScript package [`canvg/canvg`](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) in browser.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/canvg@3.0.4/lib/umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="svg_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     height="300" width="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">

   <defs>
     <g id="SVG" fill="#ffffff" transform="scale(2) translate(20,79)">
        <path id="S" d="M 5.482,31.319 C2.163,28.001 0.109,23.419 0.109,18.358 C0.109,8.232 8.322,0.024 18.443,0.024 C28.569,0.024 36.782,8.232 36.782,18.358 L26.042,18.358 C26.042,14.164 22.638,10.765 18.443,10.765 C14.249,10.765 10.850,14.164 10.850,18.358 C10.850,20.453 11.701,22.351 13.070,23.721 L13.075,23.721 C14.450,25.101 15.595,25.500 18.443,25.952 L18.443,25.952 C23.509,26.479 28.091,28.006 31.409,31.324 L31.409,31.324 C34.728,34.643 36.782,39.225 36.782,44.286 C36.782,54.412 28.569,62.625 18.443,62.625 C8.322,62.625 0.109,54.412 0.109,44.286 L10.850,44.286 C10.850,48.480 14.249,51.884 18.443,51.884 C22.638,51.884 26.042,48.480 26.042,44.286 C26.042,42.191 25.191,40.298 23.821,38.923 L23.816,38.923 C22.441,37.548 20.468,37.074 18.443,36.697 L18.443,36.692 C13.533,35.939 8.800,34.638 5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 Z"/>

        <path id="V" d="M 73.452,0.024 L60.482,62.625 L49.742,62.625 L36.782,0.024 L47.522,0.024 L55.122,36.687 L62.712,0.024 L73.452,0.024 Z"/>

        <path id="G" d="M 91.792,25.952 L110.126,25.952 L110.126,44.286 L110.131,44.286 C110.131,54.413 101.918,62.626 91.792,62.626 C81.665,62.626 73.458,54.413 73.458,44.286 L73.458,44.286 L73.458,18.359 L73.453,18.359 C73.453,8.233 81.665,0.025 91.792,0.025 C101.913,0.025 110.126,8.233 110.126,18.359 L99.385,18.359 C99.385,14.169 95.981,10.765 91.792,10.765 C87.597,10.765 84.198,14.169 84.198,18.359 L84.198,44.286 L84.198,44.286 C84.198,48.481 87.597,51.880 91.792,51.880 C95.981,51.880 99.380,48.481 99.385,44.291 L99.385,44.286 L99.385,36.698 L91.792,36.698 L91.792,25.952 L91.792,25.952 Z"/>
      </g>
   </defs>

   <path id="base" fill="#000" d="M8.5,150 H291.5 V250 C291.5,273.5 273.5,291.5 250,291.5 H50 C26.5,291.5 8.5,273.5 8.5,250 Z"/>
   <g stroke-width="38.0086" stroke="#000">
     <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
       <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b" 
         d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/>
     </g>
   </g>
   <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/>
   <use xlink:href="#base" opacity="0.85"/>
   <use xlink:href="#SVG"/>
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
var svg_content=document.getElementById('svg_logo').outerHTML;
window.onload = () => {

    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    v = canvg.Canvg.fromString(ctx, svg_content);//'<svg width="600" height="600"><text x="50" y="50">Hello World!</text></svg>');

    // Start SVG rendering with animations and mouse handling.
    v.start();

    var MIME_TYPE = "image/png";

    var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL(MIME_TYPE);

    var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
    dlLink.download = fileName;
    dlLink.href = imgURL;
    dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = [MIME_TYPE, dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

    document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
    dlLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(dlLink);
};
</script>
<canvas />
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need the server to generate the png, it can't use the browser. I'm currently looking at the sharp.js package. It seems to work well enough but there are things I haven't figured out try and the examples provided aren't comprehensive.

Comment: @mahesh The reason why I post an answer of a solution running in browser is that Azure Functions for Windows does not support win32/GDI APIs. I don't know about what OS of your Azure Functions used, so please ensure your Node app deployed on Azure Functions for Linux based on Docker container.

Comment: my Function Apps are running on the windows version of azure, not linux. i'm using node.js apps and they're mostly working fine. the only issue i'm having is with converting svgs to pngs. and i'm using the sharp library (require("sharp")) to do that. i had to first change the default node.exe to 64bit.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var svg2img = require('svg2img');

    var svgString = [
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="236" height="120" ',
    'viewBox="0 0 236 120">',
    '<rect x="14" y="23" width="200" height="50" fill="#55FF55" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />',
    '</svg>'
    ].join('');

    //convert from svg string
    svg2img(svgString, function(error, buffer) {
        //returns a Buffer
        fs.writeFileSync('foo1.png', buffer);
    });


    You will find more info here:-
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2img
```

Comment: Thanks, I but I should've mentioned svg2png in the list, it didn't work in some cases, especially the ones I need, under azure. Works perfectly on node on Windows but that's not what I need. It's based on phantomjs, which isn't under development anymore. It also uses jsdom and is pretty slow in general. Did you try your code on azure? I can share the svg I'm testing. I'm currently looking at the sharp.js package. It seems to work well enough but there are things I haven't figured out try and the examples provided aren't comprehensive.